# Factoring A Matrix Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm working my way through this paper: [Down with Determinants!](http://www.axler.net/DwD.pdf)

In Section 2 (pretty much right off the bat) he gives his determinant-less proof that every finite-dimensional complex linear operator has an eigenvalue. First he says that a vector and its images under the transformation, repeated n times, can't be linearly independent, and defines $a_i$ to be the coefficients of the linear combination.

$$
a_0v + a_1Tv + \cdots + a_nT^nv=0
$$

Then he makes a (non-matrix) polynomial of those coefficients and factors it.

$$
a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_nz^n = c(z-r_1)\cdots(z-r_m)
$$

The above holds for any complex number $z$. I understand everything so far, but then he has this step, which seems to use the first equation as a polynomial of matrices:

$$
0=(a_oI + a_1T + \cdots + a_nT^n)v
= c(T-r_1I)\cdots(T-r_mI)v
$$

This seems totally non-obvious to me. I can sort of see this as an analogy with the factorization of the regular polynomial, and I verified it by hand with a generic 2-dimensional T, but I'm not sure why it works in the general case.

My main questions:

- What justifies the last step? Does it necessarily use the 2nd equation, or is that just sort of by analogy?
- In the last part, we've basically factored a polynomial of matrices. The "roots" are all constants times the identity matrix. Is this always true, or could the roots be any matrix?

Comment: If you have two polynomials $p,q$ and $p(x)=q(x)$ for all $x$, then $p(A) = q(A)$ for any suitable $A$.

Comment: @copper.hat: What you means for ''suitable''? Here, I suppose, $T-r_iI$ have to be non zero divisors... or not?

Comment: I mean square of the appropriate dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify my life, I will take the coefficients below (example, $p_k$)
as being defined for all $k$ but only non zero for a finite number of non negative integers.

If $p(x) = \sum_k p_k x^k$ we define $p(A) = \sum_k p_k A^k$.

For the first question:

If $p(x) = a(x)b(x)$, where $a,b$ are polynomials, then
$p(x) = \sum_i a_i x^i \sum_j b_j x^{j} = \sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j x^{i+j} = \sum_k \sum_i a_i b_{k-i} x^k$, hence $p_k = \sum_i a_i b_{k-i}$
(this follows since the functions $x \mapsto x^k$ are linearly independent).

Then we have 
$p(A) =  \sum_k \sum_i a_i b_{k-i} A^k = \sum_i \sum_i a_i b_j A^{i+j} =
\sum_i a_i A^i \sum_j b_j A^{j} = a(A) b(A)$.

It is easy to see that since the $A^k$ commute that $a(A)b(A) = b(A) a(A)$.

Consequently, if I write $p(x) = f_1(x)\cdots f_m(x)$, where the $f_k$
are polynomials, then $p(A) = f_1(A) \cdots f_m(A)$. (Also, the order
doesn't matter.)

If we have 
$p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_nz^n = c(z-r_1)\cdots(z-r_m)$,  then
it follows that $p(T) =a_0 + a_1 T + \cdots + a_n T^n = c(T-r_1 I)\cdots(T-r_m I)$. Since you have $p(T)v = 0$, the result follows.

For the second question:

Suppose $p(A) = 0$ for some matrix $A$. Then any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $p(\lambda) = 0$. To see this,
suppose $V^{-1}A V = J$, where $J$ is the Jordan normal form. Then you can
see that $p(A) = p(V J V^{-1}) = V p(J) V^{-1}$, so we have $p(J) = 0$.
(In fact, we have $p(J_i) = 0$ for all of the Jordan blocks.)
 Now note that the diagonal elements of $p(J)$ are $p(\lambda_k)$, where the
$\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $J$ (that is, $A$), and so $p(\lambda_k) = 0$.

As an aside, since $p(J_i) = 0$ for all of the Jordan blocks, a little work shows
that if $J_i$ is of size $d \times d$ and the eigenvalue is $\lambda$, then
$p^{(i)}(\lambda) = 0$, for $i=0,...,d-1$, so in fact we see that
$x \mapsto (x-\lambda)^d$ divides $p$.

Comment: Actually, this only addresses the first question. I'm not sure how to approach the second.

Comment: It doesn't seem apparent to me that p(VJV^-1) = Vp(J)V^-1, but that is mostly bonus material, I think. My second question was also mostly bonus/curiosity material.

Comment: Just expand the definition and notice that $A^k = V J^k V^{-1}$. Then $p(A) = \sum_k p_k A^k = \sum_k p_k V J^k V^{-1} = V (\sum_k p_k J^k ) V^{-1} = V p(J) V^{-1}$.

Comment: Actually, I think the answer to my second question is that they will always be multiples of the identity. The reason is this: in the ordinary polynomial, the $(z - r_i)$ elements are polynomials, and the $r_i$ is actually $r_i*z^0$. In the matrix polynomial, $r_i*I$ is $r_i*T^0$. Silly or not, that was my real misunderstanding ;)

Comment: Well, the second question was asking about roots of the polynomial of a matrix, so it is clear that we can use the characteristic (or better, the minimal) polynomial. But the question also asked if there were other (presumably of the same form) factorisations. This is where I got stuck!

Comment: Many of the above characterisations apply to analytic functions as well. Meaning that we can define the function of a matrix using a power series.

Comment: $A^k=VJ^kV^{-1}$ is what gets me. It seems like it should be $A^k=V^kJ^kV^{-k}$ but I haven't yet gotten to Jordan normal form (next chapter!) so I'll hold off for now.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Jordan form. It is because $A^2 = (V J V^{-1})(V J V^{-1}) = (V J (V^{-1}V) J V^{-1}) = V J^2 V^{-1}$, etc. Changing a basis doesn't change the operator.