# ((n-1)*(n+1))+1 = n^2 (perfect square when n = integer , but works for all numbers). Is there a proof for this?

Tags: proof-verification

I know that n!+1 is a perfect square.  But the equation below leads to that as well.

((n-1)*(n+1))+1 = n^2  is a perfect square where n=integer.

But is also works for fractions.
for example, the square root of 17 = 4.12310..., 
and (3.12310... * 5.12310...)+1 = 17

Is there a proof for this?

Similarly, there is a formula for cubes that seems to work for all number, and creates a perfect cube for integers:

((n-1)*n*(n+1))+n = n^3
if n=integer is a perfect cube.
but works for all values of n

proof??

Comment: if $n=3$ then $3!+1=7$ is not a perfect square...what do you mean?

Comment: Do you know that $n!+1$ is a perfect square? Note that $3!+1=7.$ On the other hand, use that $(n-1)(n+1)=n^2-1.$ So $(n-1)(n+1)+1=n^2.$ Also $(n-1)n(n+1)=n^3-n.$ Thus $(n-1)n(n+1)+n=n^3.$

Comment: `But is also works for fractions` $(x-1)(x+1)+1=x^2$ is an algebraic identity, and it works for all numbers. You could let $x = \pi$ and it would work as well.

Comment: @dxiv More precisely those polynomial equations remain true when evaluated in any *ring.* [Generally](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882417/242) a polynomial equation remains true when evaluated in any ring where the variable values and coefficients all *commute*. This is the universal property of polynomial rings, e.g. $\, x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)\,$ remains true when evaluated in any ring where $\,x,y\,$ commute. So it is not generally true in noncommutative rings, e.g. when $\,x,y\,$ are matrices, or difference or differential operators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, $n!+1$ is not necessarily a perfect square .. in fact it rarely is (it happens to be true for $n=5$, but that is one of the rare cases).

But you are correct to say that $(n-1)(n+1)+1$ is always a perfect square. The proof is simple: for any $n$: $(n-1)(n+1)+1 = n^2 + n - n -1 + 1 = n^2$

And for the last formula you get: $(n-1)n(n+1)+n = n((n-1)(n+1)+1) =$ (as we just saw) $ = nn^2 = n^3$